# I am a beginning Python learner and for one of our assignments is this but I can't understand why I am getting an error for this

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error

I am not able to understand why I am getting an error when I run this code. I am a beginner coder and for our class, we have to use a while loop to get input and display an arithmetic about what the user has entered. If someone can help, that would be great.

```
def cartypes():
    cartype_count = {}
    while True:
        car_name = input("Enter a Car Manufacturer and Model: ")
        cartype = input("What type is it (S)UV, (SE)DAN, (M)INI-VAN, (P)ICK-UP, or (O)THER? ")
        if cartype.lower() not in cartype_count:
            cartype_count[cartype.lower()] = 1
        else:
            cartype_count[cartype.lower()] += 1
        add_or_not = input("Do you want to add more cars (Y/N)? ")
        if add_or_not.lower() == "n":
            break
    
    altogether = len(cartype_count)
    print("There were", {cartype_count[S]}, "SUVs.")
    print("There were", {cartype_count[SE]}, "SEDANs.")
    print("There were", {cartype_count[M]}, "MINI-VANs.")
    print("There were", {cartype_count[P]}, "PICK-UPs.")
    print("There were", {cartype_count[O]}, "cars that were neither SUVs, SEDANs, MINI-VANs, nor PICKUPs.")

cartypes()

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mini7.py", line 21, in <module>
    cartypes()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mini7.py", line 15, in cartypes
    print("There were", {cartype_count["S"]}, "SUVs.")
KeyError: 'S'
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Hi, MattDMo, sorry for the way in which the question was posed. I fixed it and hope this should help in answering the question.

Comment: The issue is that you're passing in wrong keys. The correct keys will be 's', 'se', 'm', 'p', and 'o'. since they are strings and they're all lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in the print lines are not defined (`'s'`, `'se'`, `'m'`, `'p'`, and `'o'`. etc are not variables and are lowercase strings). Instead of

```
print("There were", {cartype_count[S]}, "SUVs.")
```

you need to use a string to access the values in the dictionary (the curly brackets are unnecessary):

```
print("There were", cartype_count["s"], "SUVs.")
```

---

You also need to make sure, that the requested keys are actually contained in the dictionary. For example, if no SUV has been registered, you will get an error when attempting `cartype_count["s"]`. You can fix this by using the dictionary `get` method, which allows you to define a default value (in this case zero):

```
print("There were", cartype_count.get("s", 0), "SUVs.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mrVerma for your help. The code works right now, and I understand now how the dictionary get method works as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @mcsoini for your help. The code works right now, and I understand now how the dictionary get method works as well.